# Private Network on restart balance and transaction is gone?

Tags: go-ethereum

I am running a private ethereum node with a single node.
and it creates a folder for the keystore and chaindata But on restart, all the data is gone even the balance as well.

`init genesis.json` is occurred only once and later only this:

> geth --gcmode archive --port 3000 --networkid 15 --nodiscover --datadir=./block-data --maxpeers=2  --rpc  --rpcaddr 0.0.0.0 --rpcport 8545 --rpccorsdomain "*" --rpcapi "eth,net,web3,personal,miner" --allow-insecure-unlock

Comment: I think `maxpeers=2` should be `maxpeers 0`. I think we need a more complete picture of your startup scripts and testing methodology to confirm that there is indeed something unexpected happening and what is causing it. Also, what version of geth?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I got the solution, when you run the network its saves keychain and nodedata on --datadir.
To make the data available while restarting the network 2 points are important :

1. Don't **init** again which is **geth init genesis.json**, it will reset.
2. Use **geth import {DIR}** , directory used in --datadir.

Comment: hi, which data directory? I think file is required in import?